# Mismatch in assembly versioning? (.Net Core 2.0 with .NET Standard 2 class library)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

So my solution compiles but when I run it I get an error in the class library that is running .NET 4.6.1.

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories' from assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Complete error:

> $exception   {System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories' from assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key, Func`3 handleFailedLookup)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetServices(Type type, Object key)
>      at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.<OfTypeIterator>d__32`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.InternalConfiguration.Lock()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.<.ctor>b__1()
>      at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
>      at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
>      at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.GetConfiguration()
>      at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.InitializeLazyInternalContext(IInternalConnection internalConnection, DbCompiledModel model)
>      at X.Y.ConfigurationModule.ConfigurationContainer..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)}  System.TypeLoadException

Comment: Are you referencing System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories?

Answer (score 1):

You see this type of errors when the assembly your are using is different from the reference assembly.

**Example**

In this condition you see this error because first one using version 3 and other using 2

[image]

[image: Version Problem]

Please do these check

> 1:Open references right click on System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories assembly
>   and check its version
>
> 2:Now open you package config or app config file and check the version of that assembly there.

**Solution**

If versions conflict please install the library from

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.Common/

Then go to bin folder delete the **'System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories'** dll also delete it from references from your project then click add references go to packages folder because the latest library you downloaded goes in this folder so just add reference.
Now right click on this assembly and copy version name and paste that version in your appconfig or packages config file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have not referenced any assembly explicitly. I have tried to get System.Data.Common from Nuget but having tried the different versions in the nuget package has not helped. It seems no matter what I try the error msg remains the same. It refers to version 4.0.0.0 which was never a version being used. Could the error be with System.Data and not System.Data.Common, then 4.0.0.0 would make more sense.

Comment: So are you still facing the same problem?

Comment: Yes the problem remains the same. The error says: "from assembly System.Data" so maybe there was never anything wrong with System.Data.Common?

Comment: Please post the complete error,try clean the solution and run vs as admin

Comment: I am running VS as admin, I have updated original question with complete error, only renamed our internal namespace.

Comment: Could be as easy as DbProviderFactories class not being available in .NET Standard 2.0, found this: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/356

Comment: I have the same issue, was it resolved or must we wait for core 2.1?